# How to parse a text file based on tabs in Python?

Tags: python

How to parse this text file:

```
mapping apple
    v1: v1a : v1b
mapping ball
    v2: v2a : v2b
```

to get

`{'apple':['v1','v1a','v1b'], 'ball':['v2','v2a','v2b']}`

There can be multiple V's under a single mapping like:

`mapping apple`

`v1: v1a : v1b`

`v2: v2a : v2b`

`v3: v3a : v3b`

`mapping ball`

`v1: v1a : v1b`

`v2: v2a : v2b`

This is what I have tried so far:

```
copy=False
for line in fh:
    if line.strip()=="mapping_start":
        copy=True
    elif line.strip()=="mapping_end":
        copy=False
    elif copy:
        if line.find('#')==-1 and len(line.strip())>0:
            #make a dictionary here
```

Comment: I was trying something of this sort but I need a mapping_start and mapping_end everytime. `copy=False
            for line in fh:
                if line.strip()=="mapping_start":
                    copy=True
                elif line.strip()=="mapping_end":
                    copy=False
                elif copy:
                        #make a dictionary here`

Comment: Where are these `"alias_start"` and `"alias_end"` that you are looking for in the text file?

Comment: @SunalMittal Please add the code to your question, not in a comment, since it belongs to the actual question. Comments should not contain vital information.

Comment: @Evert he edited the comment. It is better if you do it Sunal..

Comment: Why `mapping_start` instead of `mapping start`? Your code seems out of touch with the example data.

Comment: Sorry for all the confusion. I don't have a specific way to parse the text file but this is what I did when there was a start and end to every block. Since now there is no start and end, just the mapping keyword, it is hard to extract the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), that doesn't make it necessary to identify starts and ends. You just need to identify 'mapping' lines and all other lines holding the values:

```
from collections import defaultdict

fH = """mapping apple
    v1: v1a : v1b
mapping ball
    v2: v2a : v2b"""

result = defaultdict(list)
for line in fH.splitlines():
  if 'mapping' in line:
    key = line.split()[1]
  else:
    for values in line.split(':'):
      result[key].append(values.strip())

print(result)
```

Returns:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'apple': ['v1', 'v1a', 'v1b'], 'ball': ['v2', 'v2a', 'v2b']})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("lol.txt", 'r') as config:
    adict = {}
    for line in config.readlines():
        if 'mapping' in line:
            key = line.strip().split()[-1]
        else:
            line = line.replace(' ', '').strip()
            adict[key] = line.split(':')
```

Comment: This would work just in the case when there is just one set of values for `line.split(':')` but the first answer provides a solution to multiple set of values under apple or ball by using defaultdict(list) and append function.

Comment: this would work with any number of values

Comment: `mapping apple
        v1: v1a : v1b
        v3: v3a : v3b
mapping ball
        v2: v2a : v2b`

Comment: my solution is almost the same as the first answer, just slightly different

Comment: In this case, v1 and v3 are in separate lines so wouldn't the value be overwritten by v3?

Comment: just test it and see the output

Comment: I tested it and as expected, it assigns what ever is the value of the last 'V' under each mapping. I hope I am clear enough in describing the input, each mapping has multiple v1,v2,v3 under it and hence appending is the only option.

Comment: don't understand you, sry

Comment: `mapping apple 
v1: v1a : v1b 
v2: v2a : v2b 

mapping ball 
v2: v2a : v2b`

Comment: I see, you right, use the first answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) and combination of [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) and [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) functions to escape unnecessary checks:

```
import re

input_data = '''
mapping apple
        v1: v1a : v1b
mapping ball
        v2: v2a : v2b
'''

#   convert input to list
input_data = input_data.strip().split('\n')
#   create iterator
iterate_over = iter(input_data)
#   declare output dictionary
output = {}

#   start iteration
for line in iterate_over:
    match = re.findall(r'(?<=^mapping\s)\w+$', line)
    if match:
        try:
            output.update({match[0]: re.sub(r'\s+', '', next(iterate_over)).split(':')})
        except StopIteration:
            break

print(output)
```